# Is there a way to add custom REST actions in Feathers?

Tags: feathersjs

I am building a backend in feathers. One of the routes in the API spec is:

`/people/{pid}/userData:updatePassword`

Is there a way to add this custom action to a people or UserData controller ?

Also is there a way to implement one service which have also it subroutes included. For example: I have a `/family` service. I also have a `/family/{fid}/members`. Is there a way to include the `members`part in the  family service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP discourages putting actions into the URL and Feathers enforces this a little more strictly than many other frameworks. A good example why actions that modify data shouldn't be done through a `GET` request would be a `/users/:userid/delete` route where e.g. the Google crawler can come in and wipe your entire site.

To create, modify and remove data is what the POST, PATCH, PUT and DELETE HTTP methods and the respective [Feathers service methods](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html) `.create`, `.patch`, `.update` and `.remove` are for.

So instead of your suggested `/people/{pid}/userData:updatePassword` you would do `PATCH /people/{pid}` with a `{ "password": "newPassword" }` JSON body.

To create a route like `/family/{fid}/members` you can find more information [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#route-parameters), additionally see the [FAQ entry on nested routes](https://docs.feathersjs.com/faq/readme.html#how-do-i-do-nested-or-custom-routes).

Comment: I understand about the patch. I was following this guide https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/custom_methods. Is there a way to use verbs in that way?


Is there a way to use nested routes without building  a second service?

Comment: You can always register your own [Express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) but Feathers does not do anything more to support this (additionally, nested routes are not easy to use through websockets which is a big features of Feathers).